# Save as Dialogue showing up in IE and Firefox but not in Google chrome

Tags: struts2

In my struts2 application, I have to download the report based on given values. While downloading, IE and Firefox prompts for save as dialogue box. But Google chrome automatically download reports in Download folder. 
I searched in Google and got answer like I need to add octect-stream to contentType header. I configured it in my struts xml. Still chrome is not prompting to show save as dialogue.

Below is my code

```
<action name="exportpsrdetails" class="com.action.Export_With_All">
<result name="success" type="stream">
<param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
<param name="contentType">octet-stream</param>
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="ExportPsr.xls"</param>
<param name="inputName">excelStream</param> </result>
<result name="input">done.jsp</result>
<result name="login" type="redirect">login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

PS: I should not change settings in chrome to show save as dialogue box

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

I had face this and below help me. Add:

```
<param name="Content-Disposition">attachment;filename="ExportPsr.xls"</param>
```

you don't need to remove this !

```
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="ExportPsr.xls"</param>
```